# Would a question about choice of font size be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am a programmer who saw this site "from" *StackOverflow* in hope to ask here for help with a specific problem. The reason I post this question here is because I fear that my question might not fit allowed topics for this site, so I want to check if it is valid before I post it.

I have a rectangle ( cell of a table ) that should contain text in it. The problem is that I need to calculate font size, so the text can fit into rectangle. **Cel size depends on the paper size ( I am coding printing application ).**

Colleagues at *StackOverflow* could not help me with this, and *Mathematics* community was very close but ultimately failed as well.

In a nutshell, this is the most important information about the question I would ask.

Is this question suitable for this site ( and if it is, can you suggest me proper tags )?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are printing using TeX, then yes it's on topic, if you are not printing using TeX then it's fairly clearly off topic. (I could not tell from your question here which of those applies)

Comment: It is off-topic then... Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: You might consider asking under the [{typography} tag at Graphic Design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography).

Comment: Although it has already been stated that is off-topic, the fact, that fonts may come from very different sources (TrueType, PostScript, Metafont), it would be difficult to combine a generic approach to handle all of the art of typography, graphics design and mathematics of fonts.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close on this question. This seems like an on-topic question, as it is about TeX.SX, in particular about whether something is on-topic for TeX.SX or not. And it seems to me that the comment from @DavidCarlisle ought to be converted into an answer. Or maybe it's a duplicate of some question that's already been asked, but this definitely seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @AdamLiter yes I agree there is nothing off topic about _this_ question. I'll answer as you suggest.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the off topic question was the (not asked) question about fonts on the main site, not this meta question asking if the other question would be on topic:-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are printing using TeX, then yes it's on topic, if you are not printing using TeX then it's fairly clearly off topic.